# MongoDB slow aggregate time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization, aggregation-framework

I'm facing an issue where the aggregate function is performing very slowly where it takes about 30 seconds to gather all my data. Assume 1 of the record in this structure:

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid":"5909a5cefece40f172895a6b"
    },
    "Record":1,
    "Link":"https://www.google.com",
    "Location":["loc1", "loc2", "loc3"],
    "Organization":["org1", "org2", "org3"],
    "Date":2017,
    "PeoplePPL":["ppl1", "ppl2", "ppl3"]
}
```

And the aggregate query as follows:

```
db.testdata_4.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$PeoplePPL"
},{
    "$unwind": "$Location"  
},{
    "$match": {
        Date: {
            $gte: lowerBoundYear,
            $lte: upperBoundYear
        }
    }
},{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "People": "$PeoplePPL",
            "Date": "$Date"
        },
        Links: {
            $addToSet: "$Link"
        },
        Locations: {
            $addToSet: "$Location"
        }
    }
},{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.People",
        Record: {
            $push: {
                "Country": "$Locations",
                "Year": "$_id.Date",
                "Links": "$Links"
            }
        }
    }
}]).toArray()
```

There are a total of 154 records in the "testdata_4" collection, and upon aggregation, there will be 5571 records returned with the query time of 28 seconds. I have performed the `ensureIndex()` on "Locations" and "Date". Is this supposed to be normal as the number of records returned increases?

If it isn't normal, may I know if there's a workaround to decrease my query time to 5 seconds at max instead of having it at 28 seconds or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that the index on `Date` isn't being used.

The `$match` and `$sort` operators can take advantage of indexes when they are being used [at the beginning of the pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes). In this case, the filters are applied after several $unwind stages, which mean it likely isn't be used.

Suggestions:

1. Move the $match stage to the beginning of the pipeline
2. The "Location", "Date" and "Link" fields aren't arrays, so it isn't immediately clear why there are $unwind aggregation stages on these fields. You may want to remove these.